# Borderless button in linearlayout with layout_weight in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

this is the layout code

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapOptions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/mapOptionMenuShade"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="@string/map" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/Shade2"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnSatellite"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="@string/satellite" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/Shade3"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnHybrid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="@string/hybrid" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But with those "View" i can't get to show my buttons.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/buttons.html) for the google's example for borderland buttons. This is why i implimented thos views.

Here i want to **show 3 borderless buttons that fills the whole linear layout**.

---

|-1--|-2--|-3--|
|----|----|----|

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Button` you can use **any** View and attach onClickListener to it. So if you want borderless button, use `TextView` instead and you will get what you want. Try:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/BtnSatellite"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="@string/satellite" />
```

instead of your

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnSatellite"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="@string/satellite" />
```

(basically start with replacing `Button` with `TextView`). Remember to adjust your code if you call `findViewById()` and cast result to `Button` you will get Cast Exception if you left it not updated.

**EDIT**

Alternative approach is [described in developers' docs "Borderless button"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Borderless), however it requires device running at least API11 (Honeycomb), so use wisely.

Answer (score 0):

To create the borderless button, you need to add the following to your XML code for the buttons. This is new to API 11 (Honeycomb)

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Alternatively, you can simply use a textView or ImageView for your buttons.